# Apache Ignite AWS ELB based discovery - LoadBalancerNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, ignite, amazon-elb

Our developer is trying to use Apache Ignite through AWS ELB based discovery as described here : 
https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/amazon-aws#amazon-elb-based-discovery

The application gets deployed in ECS. and the traffic is controlled by an ALB (elbv2).

While starting the application i'm getting the below error -

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancing.model.LoadBalancerNotFoundException: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'my-elb-name' (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: LoadBalancerNotFound; Request ID: xxxxx

The user is given Read permission for the ELB.

Comment: AWS ALB/NLB use elbv2 API. The classic ELB uses elb API (the original API). Two different APIs. I have not used Apache Ignite so I cannot advise how to select the API to use but maybe this tip will help.

Comment: perhaps, the specified load balancer was not created. Please take a look at this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ts-as-loadbalancer.html#ts-as-loadbalancer-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks John,
Yes it was because the developer was using the usual API whereas the we are using an ALB which uses elbv2 API. I suggested the developer to use the below link to use the methods and it worked ! They were able to describe the ALB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticloadbalancingv2/AmazonElasticLoadBalancing.html